# /etc/fstab Modification problem

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab, etc

This is what my file look like and every time I try to remount by typing 
`sudo mount -o remount /tmp/mnt2` it's the same error `line 13 in /etc/fstab is bad`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=dc3c8918-9c1e-4706-ab05-be5d24888e60 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=e5298614-4ffc-48ff-beaa-6cc8287de1cc none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
/dev/sdb2 /tmp/mnt2 ext3 defaults usrquota,grpquota 0 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mount options should be separated by a comma. In your case, there is a space between `defaults` and `usrquota,grpquota`.

```
/dev/sdb2 /tmp/mnt2 ext3 defaults,usrquota,grpquota 0 2
```

Comment: What about the options `usrquota` and `grpquota`? `man mount` tells that these are options for `affs`, not for `ext3`.

Comment: @mook765 Look carefully. The last mount option for `ext3` says `"Apart from the old quota system (as in ext2, jqfmt=vfsold aka version 1 quota) ext3 also supports..."`. Under `Mount options for ext2` there is mention of `grpquota|noquota|quota|usrquota`.

Comment: Thanks, nice shot with the comma anyway, I looked for the options first as I never saw them before...